# logout/login not enough to update group membership

Tags: gnome, login, group, cinnamon

I just added myself to "docker" group on my workstation.
I dutifully logged out and in again on my desktop environment but I'm still not on the group:

```
mcon@cinderella:~$ id
uid=1000(mcon) gid=1000(mcon) groups=1000(mcon),20(dialout),27(sudo),46(plugdev),115(lpadmin),124(vboxusers)
mcon@cinderella:~$ grep mcon /etc/group
dialout:x:20:mcon,mauro
sudo:x:27:mcon
plugdev:x:46:mcon
mcon:x:1000:
lpadmin:x:115:mcon
vboxusers:x:124:mauro,mcon
docker:x:136:mcon
```

I'm under an up-to-date Debian Sid.
My desktop is Gnome/Cinnamon

I *know* this can be fixed by rebooting, but I would like to understand what's going on.

Note that using the "su trick" actually works:

```
mcon@cinderella:~$ su - mcon
Password: 
mcon@cinderella:~$ id
uid=1000(mcon) gid=1000(mcon) groups=1000(mcon),20(dialout),27(sudo),46(plugdev),115(lpadmin),124(vboxusers),136(docker)
```

WHY logging out and then in again does not?

*UPDATE*: further investigation shows that *after logout* there still are a ton of processes running with my userid, including systemd, sh, various gvfs-whatever, gpg-agent, etc.
Killing the shell did not change anything and but I'm a bit scared about killing them all.
Logging-out shouldn't end all activities in my behalf?
This looks like a security hole (or not?).
I will try to kill all those processes to see if something is "keeping session alive" (at worst I'll have to reboot).

*Update2 (as asked by @StephenKitt)*:

```
mcon@cinderella:~$ loginctl show-user $(whoami)
UID=1000
GID=1000
Name=mcon
Timestamp=Sat 2019-03-23 15:01:35 CET
TimestampMonotonic=24931331
RuntimePath=/run/user/1000
Service=user@1000.service
Slice=user-1000.slice
Display=2
State=active
Sessions=2
IdleHint=no
IdleSinceHint=1553356954121832
IdleSinceHintMonotonic=7284187020
Linger=no
```

*Update3 (inspired by @StephenKitt)*:

Apparently session2 exists, but seems to be the only one present... but 
the command without argument gives a different view and says there's 
only one active session. I'm quite confused; where does the "Sessions=2" 
above come from?

```
mcon@cinderella:/tmp/ca$ loginctl show-session
EnableWallMessages=no
NAutoVTs=6
KillUserProcesses=no
RebootToFirmwareSetup=no
IdleHint=no
IdleSinceHint=1553356954121832
IdleSinceHintMonotonic=7284187020
BlockInhibited=handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key:handle-lid-switch
DelayInhibited=shutdown:sleep
InhibitDelayMaxUSec=30s
UserStopDelayUSec=10s
HandlePowerKey=poweroff
HandleSuspendKey=suspend
HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
HoldoffTimeoutUSec=30s
IdleAction=ignore
IdleActionUSec=30min
PreparingForShutdown=no
PreparingForSleep=no
Docked=yes
LidClosed=no
OnExternalPower=yes
RemoveIPC=yes
RuntimeDirectorySize=3314405376
InhibitorsMax=8192
NCurrentInhibitors=7
SessionsMax=8192
NCurrentSessions=1
mcon@cinderella:/tmp/ca$ loginctl show-session 2
Id=2
User=1000
Name=mcon
Timestamp=Sat 2019-03-23 15:01:35 CET
TimestampMonotonic=24933340
VTNr=7
Seat=seat0
Display=:0
Remote=no
Service=lightdm
Desktop=lightdm-xsession
Scope=session-2.scope
Leader=2009
Audit=2
Type=x11
Class=user
Active=yes
State=active
IdleHint=no
IdleSinceHint=1553356954121832
IdleSinceHintMonotonic=7284187020
LockedHint=no
```

Comment: How did you log out? Are you running a GUI?

Comment: @roaima: yes, as said I'm using cinnamon. I simply logout from menu->Logout->LeaveSession. This drops me in lightdm, from there I give again user/pass.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the Gnome/Cinnamon bit. You're right, though: logging out and in again should have fixed it.

Comment: @roaima: please see Question update.

Comment: What does `loginctl show-user $(whoami)` show, when you’re logged in?

Comment: @StephenKitt: I updated the question as asked. I'm wondering where that "Sessions=2" comes from.

Comment: That is curious indeed. I was wondering whether you had “linger” enabled, but you don’t, so that doesn’t explain things...

Comment: @StephenKitt: also "Display=2" does not look right (I have just one monitor, large, 4k, but still ONE). This is after a reboot/login; I didn't mess with anything since.

Comment: `Display=2` is fine, it’s not the number of displays, it’s the id of the display you’re running in; you can see details with `loginctl show-session 2`.

Comment: @StephenKitt: further update of Question, can you divine what's happening?

Comment: `Sessions=2` is also fine, it’s the list of session ids you have, not the number of sessions ;-). There’s nothing wrong with your sessions AFAICT, I’m still trying to remember what causes the user session to persist (for a short while) after logout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out logout will *not* close all processes running on user behalf.
Logging on Linux console (Ctrel-Alt-F1) as root and issuing `killall -HUP -u mcon` resolves the issue.

Note: the above command will *not* terminate all processes having effective uid "mcon" (in particular systemd, dbus-daemon and several others resist), but it seems enough to cure the "group reloading" problem.

I'm still wondering why logout does not really clear after itself, though.